# Magento creating index.html files on root of hosting dir

Tags: magento-1.8

My magento install creates many index.html files on root of web hosting dir (ie, outside public_html folder). Over one month created thousands of these files, taking up to 300MB of space. The files are incremental.

index.html index.html.1 etc

each one is about 50KB and the content is the content of the html of home page...

Is this sometithing to do with the cache system? How to turn off to avoid goid over quota of web space?

Cheers

Comment: Check your cron. My case is different with you. Previously I set up cron using this command `/usr/bin/wget http://www.domain.com/cron.php`. This creates a lot of cron.php files in my root hosting directory each time the cron run. Then I changed the command to `/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cron.php`. And now it's stop generating that cron.php files.

Comment: This **is not** standard Magento behavior!! You have something else going on that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Magento itself does not create any html files outside magento installation folder.

All magento cache data is stored in var/cache in magento installation folder.

That could never happened with clear magento installation.

So my advise to you is to check all your extensions which are installed, maybe one of them does that. Also you can try to search in code for 'index.html' and maybe find the place where these files are creating.

Comment: Also, Please tell to Server provider check the any suspected file is automatically creating the files

Comment: I turned off all cache options and full page cache and still the index.html files with 64kb are created... My hoster tells me he has no way to confirm how the files are being created.... I have a fresh magento 1.8.1 install with a theme from Magento Connect and just 2 plugins. One for social buttons on pages and the other an admin theme.... weird....

Comment: If I have no way to detect how these files are created, how can I auto delete them with cron?

Comment: Not a Magento cache function so disabling cache won't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you involve a security expert to do a Pentest and check if any malware injected into system.If so clean that and check.

As Magento will not create any files out of system  and whatever it creates is generally in var folder.

Also check if there are other softwares like Word press in your system.As wordpress is an easy hack target if not updated and secured.